# If f is multiplicative, then will $f\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$ be multiplicative for coprime $a,b$?

Tags: functions, multiplicative-function

Given that $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers, i.e 
 $gcd(a,b)=1$ then for any multiplicative function $f$ will $f\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$ be multiplicative? i.e Will following property hold

$$f\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) =f(a) \cdot f\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)$$

If it is true, please explain proof or intuition behind it.

Comment: $f$ is multiplicative with respect to what?

Comment: @FlorisClaassens I don't know what you are asking. I am studying this for first time and encountered while reading [linear sieve](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/54090). Here it is given that f is defined on all integers. I hope that is what you are asking.

Comment: @FlorisClaassens Are you asking about specific function which you want to know? My question is about any function.

Comment: $f(a/b)$ is $f(a$ \setminus $b)$?

Comment: @Jneven no it is f(a divides b)

Comment: @Jneven thanks for edit. I am new to this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is only defined on the integers, then $f(a/b)$ is not defined for any integers $a,b$ except if $b$ divides $a$, i.e. $gcd(a,b)=b$. So your question does not really make sense.

What you can do if $f(a)\neq 0$ for all integers $a\neq 0$, is extend $f$ to all fractions by for all integers $f(a/b)=f(a)/f(b)$. This $f$ is still multiplicative on the rational numbers as for all fractions $\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}\in\mathbb{Q}$ we have. (i.e. all the fractions.)
$$f(\frac{a}{b}\cdot \frac{c}{d})=f(\frac{ac}{bd})=\frac{f(ac)}{f(bd)}=\frac{f(a)f(c)}{f(b)f(d)}$$
where the last equality is due to the multiplicity of $f$ on the integers.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you tell reason why f will be multiplicative for all rational?

Comment: And what when $b$ divides $a$ if $f$ is defined on integer

Comment: If $b$ divides $a$ then $a/b$ is an integer, so if $f$ is defined on the integers $f(a/b)$ exists. If $b$ does not divide $a$, then $a/b$ is not an integer and $f(a/b)$ is undefined as $a/b$ is not in the domain of $f$.